# Qt 5.4 Libraries and Netbeans 8 on OS X

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans, header, include

I've searched through multiple questions on StackOverflow as well as other forums on the web, but I can't find an answer to this problem.

I'm trying to use Netbeans to build a Qt application (I prefer Netbeans over most other IDEs), and Netbeans can't seem to find some of the Qt libraries.  I've added cmake/qmake to my C++ compiler paths, and included all the bin and lib folders in the Qt folder. I've also made sure that all necessary Qt modules are checked under Project Properties > Build > Qt > Qt Modules.

For example, the following include statement works, and Netbeans finds QtCore:

```
#include <QtCore>
```

However, Netbeans will warn about "unresolved includes" within QtCore, or any other module.  Going into QtCore.h shows that many headers included in this file are not found or have unresolved includes as well.

I've physically tracked down those headers and included their directories in my project. What is my project configuration missing?

Comment: Have you tested `Code Assistance -> Reparse Project`?

Comment: multiple times. it seems netbeans just isn't compatible

Comment: It is compatible. If in doubt, you can open an [issue](https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html). Btw. it's not necessary to add qt's bin / lib folder to the project, this is usualy done through system path automatically. Just for validation: If you setup a completly new QT project using the new project wizzard (without any change), does this fail too?

Comment: It used to. I followed the steps below after reinstalling homebrew (so Qt would install), and everything is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you have installed latest QT from http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/ or from http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2

These latest installation should be detected by NetBeans. If this also doesn't work try doing following steps -

1. If you dont have homebrew installed, install it from http://brew.sh/
2. Later in terminal do **brew install qt5**
3. Do **brew linkapps qt5** or **brew link --force qt5**
4. Later do **ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.4.1/mkspecs /usr/local/mkspecs**  &  **ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.4.1/plugins /usr/local/plugins**

These steps should definitely solve your QT detection problem.

Comment: After some homebrew maintenance, the above steps worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The steps provided by Tushar worked perfectly. I also took an extra step of pointing Netbeans to the qmake command under Preferences > C/C++. Not sure if this is absolutely required, but I did it just for peace of mind.